# Getting a path and then converting it to a string?

Tags: powershell

```
$getusers = Get-ChildItem \\pc-name\c$\users\ | Select-Object Fullname
```

I'm running that line to get all the users who have logged into a pc.

Then I am checking every documents folder for files. I assumed it would be as simple as this:

```
foreach ($user in $getusers) {
Get-ChildItem "$user\documents"
}
```

but it seems that I have to convert the $getusers to string? Can someone help and explain what needs to be done?  I think its simple I'm just not getting.

Comment: Post the output you're getting when you try this...

Answer (score 1):

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem \\pc-name\c$\users\ | Select-Object FullName | Where-Object {!($_.psiscontainer)} | foreach {$_.FullName}
```

This ended up working.  I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Putting `| Where-Object {!($_.psiscontainer)} | foreach {$_.FullName}` after the `Select-Object` is misleading and redundant. `$_.psiscontainer` would be null since you removed all properties with the earlier `select` except for `FullName`. Also, since you already selected `FullName` you would not need to output it again with `ForEach`.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else finds this in there search for help I wanted to add what I think the actual issue is. Consider the following line:

```
$getusers = Get-ChildItem \\pc-name\c$\users\ | Select-Object Fullname
```

That would return an object of `fullname`s.

```
 FullName                                                                       
--------                                                                                                                   
\\localhost\c$\users\jpilot                                                    
\\localhost\c$\users\matt                                               
\\localhost\c$\users\misapps                                                   
\\localhost\c$\users\mm
```

The issue is that `$getusers` is a `System.Object[]` that has FullName NoteProperty and not a `System.String[]` as the loop would be expecting. What should be done in the following

```
$getusers = Get-ChildItem \\pc-name\c$\users\ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
```

Now `$getusers` will contain an array of string

```
\\localhost\c$\users\jpilot                                                    
\\localhost\c$\users\matt                                               
\\localhost\c$\users\misapps                                                   
\\localhost\c$\users\mm
```

That would make the rest of the script function as expected.